# vba searching xml result and pulling specific info into excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to pull in information from Zillow into an excel sheet.
I have a list of properties in column A formatted in zillows required format for entry via their API.  I want my code to run for each property in my column and return the Zpid and Zestimate into my table in Column J and K.  I've started with the following where the AA range is where I've concatenated the address as I mentioned above to incorporate Zillows required string.  I'm not sure if it is working down through the column as when I use Msg.Box Http.ResponseText I don't see it as a string.  But the code that returns (See Below) comes in when I enter into the url manually.

```
    Private Sub btnRefresh_Click()
 Dim W As Worksheet: Set W = ActiveSheet
 Dim Last As Integer: Last = W.Range("aa300").End(xlUp).Row
 Dim Purported As String
 Dim i As Integer
 For i = 2 To Last
    Purported = Purported & W.Range("AH" & i).Value & "+"
 Next i
 Purported = Left(Purported, Len(Purported) - 1)

 Dim URL As String: URL =  "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?zws-id=X1-ZWz1f9iajlak23_7kib9&address=" & Purported
 Dim Http As New WinHttpRequest
 Http.
```

I test it in a browser and it returns the following in breif:

```
<zpid>88964519</zpid>
<links>
<homedetails>
http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/7736-SE-72nd-Ave-Portland-OR-    97206/88964519_zpid/
</homedetails>
<graphsanddata>http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/7736-SE-72nd-Ave-Portland-OR-97206/88964519_zpid/#charts-and-data
</graphsanddata>
<mapthishome>http://www.zillow.com/homes/88964519_zpid/</mapthishome>
<comparables>http://www.zillow.com/homes/comps/88964519_zpid/</comparables>
</links>
<address>
<street>7736 SE 72nd Ave</street>
<zipcode>97206</zipcode>
<city>Portland</city>
<state>OR</state>
<latitude>45.467339</latitude>
<longitude>-122.589271</longitude>
</address>
<zestimate>
<amount currency="USD">243161</amount>
```

I want to import the "Zpid" and the "Zestimate" into my spreadsheet
for each

I'm a newbie at this code stuff and trying to learn.  Appreciate any help I get.  Thanks,

Comment: [Simple google search](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.02.heyscriptingguy.aspx)

Comment: There are several libraries for working with XML files. Here is one good resource: http://analystcave.com/vba-xml-working-xml-files/

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a huge variety of ways to solve this problem, and it's not clear which part is giving you trouble. That said, here's my example of a subroutine that finds the Zpid and Zestimate given a valid address string. Hopefully it helps:

> The below code requires that Microsoft XML is added to the VBAProject references.

```
Sub Zillow(addressPart As String)
    Dim httpRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP, xmlParser As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set xmlRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Set xmlParser = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    requestURL = "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?zws-id=X1-ZWz1f9iajlak23_7kib9&address=" & addressPart

    xmlRequest.Open "GET", requestURL, False
    xmlRequest.Send

    xmlParser.LoadXML xmlRequest.responseText

    Zpid = xmlParser.SelectSingleNode("//zpid").Text
    Zestimate = xmlParser.SelectSingleNode("//zestimate/amount").Text
End Sub
```

That should put the Zpid and Zestimate values into those variables. Obviously you'll have to make some modifications to loop this through all of your data and fill in the corresponding cells.